# Json parsing or passing headers in RabbitMQ

Tags: php, json, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I want pass multi value to a queue which provided by RabbitMQ via PHP. It's a SMS sender that has mobile number and content.

Is it better to send this two parameters as a json string to queue's payload and on consumer's side pars json, Or, send mobile number as a header parameter and content as payload and using `get("application_headers")` and `getNativeData` on consumer's side to use mobile number?

Which way has better performance?

Answer (score 1):

generally speaking, the data should be included in the body of the message - and is typically sent as JSON

headers are usually reserved for metadata - information that is related to the message, but not directly a part of the message.

as a real-world example, when you send a letter through the postal system, you put the letter in an envelope. the address to which the letter should be delivered, the return address, and a postal stamp are attached to the envelope.

the "to" and "return" addresses, as well as the "stamp" could be considered "header" information. they are important and are needed to ensure the letter is processed correctly and delivered to the right destination. but these things are not part of the actual contents of the letter that is contained in the envelope.